# Use of Topological Sort in Domain Name Server

Tags: domain-name

**Is there any application of Topological Sort in Domain Name Server?**

I've been asking myself whether there is any use of it, in Web Servers to resolve Server Redirection?

Comment: Have you tried googling *toposort DNS*? No results. There you go.